# Find " ' " in a text Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to found if a varchar contains a `'` using the `LIKE` option.

I think it's something like that

```
select * 
from table 
where field like '%'%'
```

but a bit different.

Comment: `select * from table where field like $thing$%'%$thing$` ?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answering about escaping single quote:

you can use dollar sign quoting:

```
select * from table where field like $thing$%'%$thing$;
```

or use E before quote:

```
select * from table where field like e'%\'%'
```

or two single quotes:

```
select * from table where field like '%''%'
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Note that the first two solutions are non-standard SQL and only apply to Postgres.

Comment: sorry - I did not notice other tags. my bad